# Twitter API - check if username exists

Tags: twitter

I just want to check if a `username`  exists in Twitter. I thought  it would be part of the API, but cannot find it on the api wiki http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation.

Any ideas?

thanks

JP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that I can pass screenname in the user search API.  And I have to check for 404 not found status (if username does not exist). Seems a bit ugly, but might just work. Better suggestions welcome!

this gives 404:
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=thisdoesnotexist1234abxfd

this returns valid info:
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=billgates

thanks

JP

EDIT

> The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API
>   v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.

Answer (score 0):

@JP Even if the twitter api rate limit has been reached , 404 would be returned. SO this is as you said a dirty method. take into consideration the rate limit and add sufficient checks in your code so as not to reach them. the above method should work fine.
regards,

Comment: Just to be current, I know this to be false. They've handled this so that all requests past 150/hr return a 400.